# Connect 2 columns to 1 column

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

I need to connect 2 columns to 1 column, but I can't figure it out how to connect those columns.
This is how it looks like:

Table(appointment)

```
-------------------------------------------
| id | home | salesman | buyer |   date   |
| 1  |  3   |    2     |   4   | 12-6-2016|
| 2  |  1   |    1     |   3   | 15-6-2016|
| 3  |  2   |    5     |   6   | 20-6-2016|
-------------------------------------------
```

Table(person)

```
---------------------------------------------------------
| id | name |      email     | phonenumber | permission |
| 1  | John | John@gmail.com |  12345678   |     1      |
| 2  | Jack | Jack@gmail.com |  12345678   |     1      |
| 3  | Henk | Henk@gmail.com |  12345678   |     0      |
| 4  | Mike | Mike@gmail.com |  12345678   |     0      |
| 5  | Tom  | Tom@gmail.com  |  12345678   |     1      |
| 6  | Ben  | Ben@gmail.com  |  12345678   |     0      |
---------------------------------------------------------
```

Table(home)

```
--------------------------------------
| id | salesman |  price  |  city    |
| 1  |    2     |  123000 | London   |
| 2  |    1     |  123000 | New York |
| 3  |    5     |  123000 |  Paris   |
--------------------------------------
```

This is how I want to see it on my php page:

```
-------------------------------------------------
| home            | salesman | buyer |   date   |
| Home in Paris   |   Jack   |  Mike | 12-6-2016|
| Home in London  |   John   |  Henk | 15-6-2016|
| Home in New York|   Tom    |  Ben  | 20-6-2016|
-------------------------------------------------
```

People with permission 1 are salesman, permission 0 are buyers.

So my question is, how can I change the numbers to the correct value? Without change the number in table appointment to values in the database...

I don't know much about SQL, so could someone please come with a solution that isn't an example and works with my tables and columns?

**Edit:**

Table(afspraak)

```
-------------------------------------------
| id | huis | verkoper | koper |  datum   |
| 1  |  3   |    2     |   4   | 12-6-2016|
| 2  |  1   |    1     |   3   | 15-6-2016|
| 3  |  2   |    5     |   6   | 20-6-2016|
-------------------------------------------
```

Table(persoon)

```
---------------------------------------------------------
| id | naam |      email     | phonenumber | rechten    |
| 1  | John | John@gmail.com |  12345678   |     1      |
| 2  | Jack | Jack@gmail.com |  12345678   |     1      |
| 3  | Henk | Henk@gmail.com |  12345678   |     0      |
| 4  | Mike | Mike@gmail.com |  12345678   |     0      |
| 5  | Tom  | Tom@gmail.com  |  12345678   |     1      |
| 6  | Ben  | Ben@gmail.com  |  12345678   |     0      |
---------------------------------------------------------
```

Table(huis)

```
--------------------------------------
| id | verkoper |  prijs  |   stad   |
| 1  |    2     |  123000 | London   |
| 2  |    1     |  123000 | New York |
| 3  |    5     |  123000 |  Paris   |
--------------------------------------
```

My php code:

```
include('config.php');
$getAfspraak = "SELECT CONCAT('Home in ', HO.stad) AS Home,
   SA.`naam` AS verkoper,
   BU.`naam` AS koper,
   AP.`datum`
FROM afspraak AP
INNER JOIN huis HO ON HO.id = AP.huis
INNER JOIN persoon SA ON SA.id = AP.verkoper AND SA.rechten = 1
INNER JOIN persoon BU ON BU.id = AP.koper AND BU.rechten = 0";
//Inner join for huis   SELECT afspraak.huis, huis.stad FROM afspraak INNER JOIN huis ON afspraak.huis = huis.id; This query should show "huis in [stad]" it means, a home in London.
$dataAfspraak = mysqli_query($con, $getAfspraak) or die(mysqli_error($con));



<table cellspacing=1 border=0 width=100%>
    <tr>
        <th>Koper</th>
        <th>Verkoper</th>
        <th>Huis</th>
        <th>Datum</th>
    </tr>
<?php while($resAfspraak = mysqli_fetch_assoc($dataAfspraak)): ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $resAfspraak['koper']?></td> <!-- value is naam if the row has 0 at rechten -->
        <td><?php echo $resAfspraak['verkoper']?></td> <!-- value is naam if the row has 1 at rechten -->
        <td><?php echo $resAfspraak['huis']?></td>
        <td><?php echo $resAfspraak['datum']?></td>
    </tr>
<?php endwhile;?>
```

Comment: `$resAfspraak['naam']` and `$resAfspraak['huis']` are not matching with the SELECT column names, is it typo or you wrongly placed. These column names should match with the column names from the SELECT block. Hope those are should be `$resAfspraak['Home']` and `$resAfspraak['koper']`

Comment: Yeah, I forgot to inner join huis from huis table, so it's kinda a typo, but the things I want to show on my page (naam, verkoper, huis and datum) are correct.

Comment: Could you confirm it should `naam` or `koper`. I mean the required fields are `koper, verkoper, huis` and `datum` right?

Comment: I'm so sorry, it's koper, verkoper, huis and datum. Koper and verkoper are getting their value from naam. Kopers are rechten = 0 and verkoper are rechten = 1. This is how it should be.

Comment: I've edited my first post. Can I add the huis' inner join on the $getAfspraak query?

Comment: Please check my updated answer

Comment: I know why your query doesn't work for me. It's because my MySQL version is outdated and the AND operator that's located after the ON statement isn't supported on the MySQL version that I have. Have you got something in mind that'll work even when it doesn't have an AND operator? Just so you know, I use usbwebserver as my localhost server.

I get the following error when using AND:
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AND SA.rechten = 0' at line 1

Comment: If `CASE` statement is works in your MySQL, you can try this `SELECT CASE WHEN BU.rechten = 1 THEN BU.naam ELSE '' END AS koper, CASE WHEN SA.rechten = 0 THEN SA.naam ELSE '' END AS verkoper, CONCAT('Huis in ', HO.stad) AS Huis, AP.datum 
FROM afspraak AP 
INNER JOIN huis HO ON HO.id = AP.huis 
INNER JOIN persoon SA ON SA.id = AP.verkoper
INNER JOIN persoon BU ON BU.id = AP.koper `

Comment: I'm sorry, I was wrong. I made a mistake and that is because koper had an id that doesn't match with rechten = 0. I really appreciate the effort you've put to fix my problem. So this means that your query worked from the beginning. Thank you very much! :)

Comment: Your answer is labelled as the correct answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the below [`JOIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html) and [`CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) query you can achieve your expected result:

```
SELECT CONCAT('Home in ', HO.city) AS Home,
       SA.`Name` AS Salesman,
       BU.`Name` AS Buyer,
       AP.`Date`
FROM Appointment AP
INNER JOIN Home HO ON HO.Id = AP.Home
INNER JOIN Person SA ON SA.Id = AP.Salesman AND SA.Permission = 1
INNER JOIN Person BU ON BU.Id = AP.Buyer AND BU.Permission = 0
```

---

**UPDATE:**

You no need to get the `huis` value from separate join. The below query returns the `koper, verkoper, huis` and `datum` values.

```
$getAfspraak = "SELECT BU.naam AS koper, SA.naam AS verkoper, CONCAT('Huis in ', HO.stad) AS Huis, AP.datum 
FROM afspraak AP 
INNER JOIN huis HO ON HO.id = AP.huis 
INNER JOIN persoon SA ON SA.id = AP.verkoper AND SA.rechten = 1 
INNER JOIN persoon BU ON BU.id = AP.koper AND BU.rechten = 0";
$dataAfspraak = mysqli_query($con, $getAfspraak) or die(mysqli_error($con));
```

Comment: Nope, I can't get it to work. What does SA, BU, AP and HO mean? Can you explain the things you use in your query?

Comment: Those are [table alias names](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp). *I can't get it to work* What is the issue, it throws error? or not return the expected result? Explain in detail

Comment: First I have to change the table names / columns to dutch words, this means that the table names and columns are translated in the first post (I wanted to make it easy for you guys). Once I'm done with the query, I reload the page, but there's nothing showing up, there's even no error. Is there a function to show an error if there's an error?

Comment: Hope I misread your question. So you need to made the change in the `Appointment` table itself, like modifying the `salesman` 2 to `Jack` in this way?

Comment: I'll just copy the code and table/column names from my php file and database to the first post. Give me 1 minute.

Comment: Php code added and the table / column names are changed to Dutch words, this is exactly how my database looks like.